# Excel - status (online/offline) corresponding to concrete number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, formatting, conditional-formatting

I cannot deal with the below tasks, and need your help!

The thing is that I need to use a formula to solve this (not just copy-paste, assuming that the data will be much bigger). Basically, I need to insert the correct status (online/offline) from column D corresponding to the code in Column C into Column B (again matching the correct status from Column A). Please also note that not all codes from Column C are present in Column A. Thank you in advance!

[image: **Screenshot:**Table example]

Comment: If only you could imagine how often different people ask about using the [**VLOOKUP() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) *and how tired we are of repeating the same thing **RTFM***! See Example 5.

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Excel you can use in `B2`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$D$26,2,FALSE),"")
```

In newer versions:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$C$26,$D$2:$D$26,"")
```

Each of these formulas produces single result an you can copy it down.
Instead of `A2` you can use in formulas the entire range `A2:A33` to get all the results at once. In new versions it will be a dynamic formula, in older ones you must select the range for results beforehand and use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.